# How to read non-English characters in filename, using Java programme

Tags: java

I'm trying to read mail in my outbox which usually contains one attached pdf file. If the pdf file name contains English characters, the function below works fine. But if the file name contains any non-English character (for example, *filename1(chinesecharacter).pdf*) my function is not able to read it. Can anybody tell me what changes I need to make in my function?

Comment: I think you mean Latin characters, and by the looks of the code you are limiting to characters in ISO-8859 encodings which is significantly beyond just the Latin character set.

Comment: can you suggest me which iso i need to use am new bee in java iso is bit confusing me

Answer (score 0):

Just simply check the ASCII (or Unicode?) values against the range(s) of values with English characters. Every character corresponds to a number in its character set.

Or you could create an array of all English characters, and check it against that. There may also be an API function in Java.

Comment: can you suggest me which iso i need to use am new bee in java iso is bit confusing me

Answer (score 0):

This line indicates you might have a problem decoding non-ISO 8859 character sets, e.g. UTF-8, due to the weak handling of RFC2822 encoded file names:

```
if(fileName.startsWith("=?iso-8859"))
{
  String strFolder = strFolderName.substring(strFolderName.lastIndexOf("/")+1,
                                             strFolderName.length());
  fileName = strFolder + ".pdf";
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word